# Why is 2,147,483,647 the max int value?

Tags: java

Can someone provide me with a detailed explanation of why **2,147,483,647** is the maximum integer value in Java?

Comment: Interestingly I don’t find anything wrong with this question.

Comment: No more rude comments under this. It is a fundamental question, more likely a duplicate, but reasonable for the site. We welcome all programming levels, so be tolerant or move on.

Comment: If you think this doesn't fit on Stackoverflow, maybe you should take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) as it's definitely a programmation oriented question, it's basic, but it has it's place here.

Answer (score 6):

Because the total value an int can hold in Java is 2^32 (2 to the power of 32, in other words a 32 bit number), for which half is reserved for negative numbers and half for positive numbers.